# C# Generic class with collection of generics with another type property

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I want to implement a universal generic type which could have a collection of another generic type and so one to infinity. The goal is to use this type to build hierarchical lists. So it can look something like this

```
public class BasicOverviewModel<T>
{
    public T OverViewModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<BasicOverviewModel<new T>> ChildOverviewModelCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible at all, or maybe I choose a wrong solution? Thanks...

Comment: The child collection should it be exactly the same as parent collection?? does the child have same type of child or different?

Comment: The child collection should be a different type than the parent

Comment: Patrick Hofman's answer should address your concerns.. If it works, accept that answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use another generic type parameter, in this code called `TChild`.

It gets a little more complicated for the parent-child relationships. This is what I have come up with.

```
public interface IBasicOverviewModel
{
}

public class BasicOverviewModel<T, TChild> : IBasicOverviewModel where TChild : IBasicOverviewModel
{
    public T OverViewModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TChild> ChildOverviewModelCollection { get; set; }
}

public class EndpointOverviewModel<T> : IBasicOverviewModel
{
    public T OverViewModel { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new BasicOverviewModel<string, BasicOverviewModel<int, EndpointOverviewModel<string>>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `BasicOverviewModel<TChild>` has only one generic type. What is its definition?

Comment: This solution throws Compiler error `Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'BasicOverviewModel<T, TChild>' requires 2 type arguments`

Comment: Perfect.. This is way addresses different children.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you!